# Find problem when try to swap row in order to make reduced row echelon form

Tags: fortran

I write a code which transform a square matrix to it's reduced row echelon form. But I faced a problem when row swapping is needed. I think the way I swapped give me wrong Output. Can anyone help me to figure out this.

[here](https://rextester.com/PIZKT2858) is my code and you can run it there. For make it easier I put it here also.

```
!there is a more direct way of entering the value of a matrix by row instead !as by column: reshape has an optional 
!argument ORDER which can be used to modify the order of filling the element !of the multidimensional array with the entries of the array constructor.

PROGRAM RREF
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL,DIMENSION(3,3)::A=reshape((/0,0,1,1,2,3,0,1,-2/), shape(A), order=(/2,1/)),TEMP_FOR_SW(1,3)
INTEGER::ROW=3,COL=3,I,J,K,SW_PRINT
WRITE(*,100)TRANSPOSE(A)
100 FORMAT(3F6.2)
DO I=1,ROW
    IF(ABS(A(I,I))<1E-2)THEN
        WRITE(*,101)I
        101 FORMAT('SWAP NEEDED ROW=',I1)
        SW_PRINT=0
        DO K=1,col,1
            IF(A(K,I)>1E-2)THEN
                TEMP_FOR_SW=A(K:K,1:3)
                A(K:K,1:3)=A(I:I,1:3)
                A(I:I,1:3)=TEMP_FOR_SW
                IF(SW_PRINT<1)THEN
                    WRITE(*,102)K
                    102 FORMAT('SWAPPED WITH ROW=',I1)
                    SW_PRINT=SW_PRINT+1
                    END IF
                END IF
            END DO
        END IF
    A(I:I,1:3)=A(I:I,1:3)/(A(I,I))
    PRINT*,'--------------------------------------------------'
    WRITE(*,100)TRANSPOSE(A)
    DO J=1,COL
        IF(J /=  I)THEN
            A(J:J,1:3)=A(J:J,1:3)-(A(I:I,1:3)*A(J,I))
            PRINT*,'--------------------------------------------------'
            WRITE(*,100)TRANSPOSE(A)
            END IF
        END DO
    END DO
END PROGRAM RREF
```

I expect the output to be

```
RowReduce[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, -2}}] // MatrixForm

1.00 0.00 0.00
0.00 1.00 0.00
0.00 0.00 1.00
```

According to Mathematica. But got this:

```
 -0.14  0.00  0.00
  0.29  1.00  0.00
  0.14  0.00  1.00
```

**Edit:** I notice that the problem was started immediate after the row swap.

Comment: Please tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Please also use some indenntation in your code, it is almost unreadable, just a wall of text. Increase the indentation level inside each loop, if condition, ssubroutine and similar.

Comment: @VladimirF Ok I will Fix it in a couple of minutes :)

Comment: Which way is the output wrong? Show also the wrong output.

Comment: @VladimirF I added it also